# Single thread programme apparently using multiple core

Tags: c++, multithreading, macos, cpu

Question summary: all four cores used when running a single threaded programme. Why?

Details: I have written a non-parallelised programme in Xcode (C++). I was in the process of parallelising it, and wanted to see whether what I was doing was actually resulting in more cores being used. To that end I used Instruments to look at the core usage. To my surprise, while my application is single threaded, all four cores were being utilised.

To test whether it changed the performance, I dialled down the number of cores available to 1 (you can do it in Instruments, preferences) and the speed wasn't reduced at all. So (as I knew) the programme isn't parallelised in any way.

I can't find any information on what it means to use multiple cores to perform single threaded tasks. Am I reading the Instruments output wrong? Or is the single-threaded process being shunted between different cores for some reason (like changing lanes on a road instead of driving in two lanes at once - i.e. actual parallelisation)?

Thanks for any insight anyone can give on this.

EDIT with MWE (apologies for not doing this initially).
The following is C++ code that finds primes under 500,000, compiled in Xcode.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    clock_t start, end;
    double runTime;
    start = clock();
    int i, num = 1, primes = 0;
    int num_max = 500000;

    while (num <= num_max) {
        i = 2;
        while (i <= num) {
            if(num % i == 0)
                break;
                i++;
        }
        if (i == num){
            primes++;
            std::cout << "Prime: " << num << std::endl;
        }

        num++;
    }

    end = clock();
    runTime = (end - start) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    std::cout << "This machine calculated all " << primes << " under " << num_max << " in " << runTime << " seconds." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This runs in 36s or thereabouts on my machine, as shown by the final out and my phone's stopwatch. When I profile it (using instruments launched from within Xcode) it gives a run-time of around 28s. The following image shows the core usage.

[instruments showing core usage with all 4 cores (with hyper threading)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiEkO.png)

Now I reduce number of available cores to 1. Re-running from within the profiler (pressing the record button), it says a run-time of 29s; a picture is shown below.

[instruments output with only 1 core available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaSqB.png)

That would accord with my theory that more cores doesn't improve performance for a single thread programme! Unfortunately, when I actually time the programme with my phone, the above took about 1 minute 30s, so there is a meaningful performance gain from having all cores switched on.

One thing that is really puzzling me, is that, if you leave the number of cores at 1, go back to Xcode and run the program, it again says it takes about 33s, but my phone says it takes 1 minute 50s. So changing the cores is doing something to the internal clock (perhaps).

Hopefully that describes the problem fully. I'm running on a 2015 15 inch MBP, with 2.2GHz i7 quad core processor. Xcode 7.3.1

Comment: We dont have any context now. Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and you will probably find an answer while composing it. If not, we will try to help.

Comment: Processor affinity is the only way you're going to keep your program from migrating between different cores as the operating system decides is appropriate. Measuring which cores are active is not a good measure, consider instead thread run/wait time.

Comment: What do you mean with "Now I reduce number of available cores to 1" if you're not just setting the affinity of your program to a single core but disable all other cores globally the would explain it: There are lots of other processes that require some CPU themselve and you're starving your prime computer of resources even if it's single threaded. The profiler tells you the wall clock time which shows how long your program itself ran - and those numbers are identical so no performance improvements.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. First of all, I wasn't sure how to limit the code to just one core directly. Since the programme (see above) is not parallel I wasn't expecting it to get moved around cores, which @BiagioFesta has explained below. The thing I find weird, is that the programme time is so much less than the "real" time. I agree that there is no performance improvement as you say: just don't know why the programme says it takes 30s, when it takes about 2 minutes according to my watch? Does reducing the core number mess with the internal clock?

Answer (score 5):

*I want to premise your answer lacks a lots of information in order to proceed an accurate diagnostic. Anyway I'll try to explain you the most common reason IHMO, supposing you application doesn't use 3-rd part component which perform in a multi-thread way.*

I think that could be a result of *scheduler effect*. I'm going to explain what I mean.

Each core of the processor takes a process in the system and executed it for a "short" amount of time. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_scheduling) is the most common solution in desktop operative system.

Your process is executed on a single core for this amount of time and then stopped in order to allow other process to continue. When your same process is resumed it could be executed in another core (always one core, but a different one). So a poor precise *task manager* with a low resolution time could register the utilization of all cores, even if it does not.

In order to verify whether the cause could be that, I suggest you to see the amount of CPU % used in the time your application is running. Indeed in case of a single thread application the CPU should be about `1/#numberCore` , in your case *25%*.

Comment: Thanks for your unbelievably quick answer, and apologies for not asking a better question. I have tried to add an MWE above. Your post seemed very logical. However, I've posted images of my Instruments output above, when running the programme with 1 core and 4 cores. When running 4 cores CPU usage is 100% or thereabouts (see the MWE I created above). CPU usage on the 1 core version is less, averaging maybe 60% (by eye). This wouldn't appear to work with your theory of getting 25% usage. Any thoughts?

Comment: @mr_phd I think my answer is still valid. As you can see in the first figure the cores are not at all saturated. That's the thread is jumping from one to another. I'm not a MAC programmer, so I'm not sure, but some *task manager* show 100% when you are using one core and 400% when you're using four cores (this is a UNIX behaviour, so it could be). At the moment my suggest could be to test an effective multithreads application and see how the task manager works

Comment: thats a good idea. I've spent the last day trying to make my Mac able to run openmp programmes. Xcode LLVM doesn't appear to support it - even though LLVM incorporates openmp these days. Am trying to command line it, and will get back to you (after posting a question about this issue!).

Comment: @mr_phd C++ now support multithread in the standard library. You can do it without OpenMP. [std thread](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/)

Comment: I didn't realise. I was obsessively trying to get OpenMP to work because the code I'm re-using has it in. I guess I'll should re-write using this approach - if only to save myself trying to get openMP to work in future! Thanks for the comments.

Comment: to answer your point earlier, you were right: the Mac CPU usage goes to 800% when I got all the cores working - using your thread idea I got it properly parallelised eventually. Plus running the clock from the header chrono gave correct times which solved my strange timing issue! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a release build your compiler may be <s>vectorising</s> parallelise  your code. Also libraries you link against, say the standard library for example, may be threaded or vectorised.

Comment: not impossible, but unlikely when using default settings. also, "vectorised" does not mean multi-threaded.

Comment: Absolutely, that should be parallelise not vectorise, thanks.

Comment: I have no experience on MacOSX/Xcode//Clang/LLDB toolchain , however , to make sure about C++ runtime, unless LLDB is giving notifications on new threads like GDB, you can try to start it with LLDB, place breakpoints on thread creation functions ( pthread_create etc ) , and if hit you could do "thread backtrace all". An alternative on Linux would be using strace for checking all syscalls  , I am guessing MacOSX equivalent is dtruss.